# PowerShell: How can I traverse through registry values named "SQLArg1", "SQLArg2" etc.?

Tags: powershell, registry

I am working on a PowerShell function that is supposed to check if two values in the registry named "SQLArg4" and "SQLArg5" (or two other numbers) are set to a certain value content and set them if not.

The problem is I cannot enumerate the values to traverse through them to compare all of them and then add my two value contents if they are not present.

I tried creating a string out of "SQLArg" and a $i index but PowerShell would not allow me to use that string as a field of a variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you only need to work with one registry key (no recursion). Try this code. It will get all the values under $key that start with "SQLArgs" and store them in $values. It loops through a number sequence and tests for the existence of the key values named SQLArgs#. When it finds one it will set the key value data.

```
$key = "HKCU:\Andy"

$values = Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name SQLArg*

1..20 | % {
    if ($values."SQLArg$_" -ne $null) {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name "SQLArg$_" -Value "Powershell Rocks"
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution. Suddenly (I don't know what I did differently before), I could use strings as property names. But your solution looks like it would work too.